# How do I make macro pull data from different sheets within a workbook. Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm having an issue with a macro used to pull information from one worksheet to another.  I cant figure out how to make the macro look at a different worksheet within the "CurrentSchedule" workbook.  When I go through the macro with the 1st (A line) worksheet everything runs smoothly, but when I try to run it through the 2nd sheet (B line) it times out.  It specifically gets stuck at the line

" Order = Range("W1").Offset(Count, 0).Value "

```
SAPorder = InputBox("Enter SAP Order Number:")
ProdLine = InputBox("Enter the sheet# of CurrentSchedule that has this   SAP order number. Example: A line = 1; B = 2")
End Select
Count = 0 'Count is the row in the designated column
Flag = True
Do While Flag
Workbooks("CurrentSchedule.xlsx").Worksheets(ProdLine).Activate
Order = Range("W1").Offset(Count, 0).Value 
If Order = SAPorder Then
nme = Range("B1").Offset(Count, 0).Value
```

Comment: You didn't qualify anything. In other words, how does the computer know which workbook/worksheet you want?

Comment: You are only showing part of the loop

Comment: What have you searched for? This is a [very common](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=VBA+data+from+other+worksheets) question.  But yes, you absolutely need to be qualifying all of your ranges....and include all the code.

Comment: @BruceWayne it's ***very*** common even if you [only look at stack overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/475578)

Comment: @macroman - oh no doubt!

Answer (score 0):

Throw away that stupid `.activate` method learn how to work with this

```
Sheets("sheetName").range("rangeName/rangeRange")[optional].cells("cellRow","cellColumn")
```

it will make your job much more easier, and then you can work with sheet/range/cell as object.

Also, when you use Range/Cell without dot and parent asignment, you working with active sheet, which may be very unpredictable. So if you use full statement, mentioned above, you cant make mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. I'm honestly pretty new with VBA and  this macro has been the way they've done this process here at my new job for a while. I'm attempting to pick it up and fix the issues with it. I appreciate your help.